# Lisp recursive square use one variables

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

This is Trying code

```
(defun f (a n)
    (if (zerop n)
        1
        (* a (f a (- n 1)))))
```

`(f 3)` should return 27, `(f 4)` should return 256

I tried using two variables, but it be against the rules.

Is it possible to use only one variable using recursive?

Thanks for any ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible:

```
(defun f (n)
  (cond
    ((numberp n)
      (f (cons n n)))
    ((zerop (car n))
      1)
    (t
      (* (cdr n)
         (f (cons (1- (car n))
                  (cdr n)))))))
```

The trick is that you can store any data structure (including a pair of numbers) in a single variable.

---

Alternatively, you can use helpers from the standard library:

```
(defun f (n)
  (apply #'*
         (loop repeat n collect n)))
```

But that doesn't use recursion. Or simply:

```
(defun f (n)
  (expt n n))
```

Comment: If you want to multiply numbers in alist , then better use REDUCE instead of APPLY. APPLY may support only lists of max length CALL-ARGUMENTS-LIMIT.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know CL, but I do know Clojure and other languages that use recursion.

In cases where a recursive function has 1 parameter acting as an accumulator, but is only set on the first call, the typical way around this is to wrap `f` in another function. There are 2 (basically the same) ways of doing this:

```
(defun g (a n)
    (if (zerop n)
        1
        (* a (g a (- n 1)))))

(defun f (n)
    ; I'm assuming you want the initial value of "a" to be 1
    (g 1 n))
```

Or, more succinctly:

```
(defun f (n)
  (let (g (fn (n)
            (if (zerop n)
              1
              (* a (g a (- n 1))))))))
    ; Instead of f being recursive, f calls g, which is recursive
    (g 1 n))
```

Excuse any syntax errors.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Regarding syntax, `(let ((g (fn (n) ...))) ...)` is written `(labels ((g (n) ...)) ...)` in CL (http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_flet_.htm)

Comment: @coredump `labels`? Would have never guessed that. I'll fix that when I get on my laptop. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Yes. it is surprising but the historical reason is interesting, and even makes sense in context: https://www.reddit.com/r/lisp/comments/k1tnl/where_does_the_special_form_labels_come_from/

Comment: @coredump Oh jeez, and double opening braces? From the point of view of someone who writes Clojure, that's very odd. That would suggest `g` is a function (which it is), but that's it's also being immediately called

Comment: Clojure needs context too: multiple arity `(defn foo ([a] a) ([] 0))`, arrays `[a b]` vs. bindings `[a b]`.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Because `labels` allows you to define multiple mutually-recursive functions.

Answer (score 1):

Using an additional variable to count down would be the sane choice, but you don't need to change the contract of just one numeric argument input just for this. You can make a helper to do that:

```
(defun exptnn (n)
  "Get the (expt n n)"
  (check-type n integer)
  (labels ((helper (acc count)
             (if (zerop count)
                 acc
                 (helper (* acc n) (1- count)))))
    (if (< n 0) 
        (/ 1 (helper 1 (- n)))
        (helper 1 n))))
```

Now to solve with without any helpers just with one argument is possible since there is a solution doing that already, but I must say that is like programming in [Brainf*ck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) without the joy!

Answer (score 1):

```
CL-USER 15 > (defun f (n)
              (labels ((g (m)
                         (if (zerop m)
                             1
                           (* n (g (1- m))))))
                (g n)))
F

CL-USER 16 > (f 0)
1

CL-USER 17 > (f 1)
1

CL-USER 18 > (f 2)
4

CL-USER 19 > (f 3)
27

CL-USER 20 > (f 4)
256

CL-USER 21 > (loop for i below 10 collect (f i))
(1 1 4 27 256 3125 46656 823543 16777216 387420489)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution where no functions with more than one parameter are used (except for `=`, `+`, `*`, `logand`, `ash`; note also that `logand` and `ash` always take a constant as second parameter so they can be implemented as unary functions too).

The idea is to "hide" the two parameters needed for the obvious recursive approach in a single integer using odd/even bits.

```
(defun pair (n)
  (if (= n 0)
      0
      (+ (* 3 (logand n 1))
         (ash (pair (ash n -1)) 2))))

(defun pair-first (p)
  (if (= p 0)
      0
      (+ (logand p 1)
         (ash (pair-first (ash p -2)) 1))))

(defun pair-second (p)
  (pair-first (ash p -1)))

(defun subsec (p)
  (if (= 2 (logand p 2))
      (- p 2)
      (+ (logand p 1) 2 (ash (subsec (ash p -2)) 2))))

(defun pairpow (p)
  (if (= (pair-second p) 1)
      (pair-first p)
      (* (pair-first p)
         (pairpow (subsec p)))))

(defun f (n)
  (pairpow (pair n)))
```

No reasonable real use, of course; but a funny exercise indeed.